# Confused about transactions within multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, transactions

I've created two databases on mysql, each containing a table called "test".

```
create table db1.test(
test_id int primary key auto_increment,
value int(5) not null);

create table db2.test(
test_id int primary key auto_increment,
value int(5) not null);
```

According to [PDO transaction across multiple databases, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388876/), PDO does not support transactions within multiple databases, but I am surprised by the results of my test. Here is my code.

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", "root", "", array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
try {
    $con->beginTransaction();
    $con->exec("use db1");
    $stmt = $con->prepare("insert into test (value) values(?)");
    $stmt->execute([1]);
    $con->exec("use db2");
    $stmt = $con->prepare("insert into test (value) values(?)");
    $stmt->execute([1]);
    $con->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $con->rollback();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The code successfully inserted with no problems. To test that the transaction I started will not work since I am using two databases, I've deleted db2.test and expect the insert on db1.test to still succeed. The insert on db2.test obviously failed, but db1.test also didn't commit.

I am confused. Why is PDO performing a transaction when I am clearly using two databases?

Also, the answer to this question:
[Multiple database and transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239810/multiple-database-and-transactions)

> That won't do squat. Transactions are isolated within a single
>   "database". In order to have transactions span across multiple
>   databases, you need what's called "distributed transaction
>   management".

Although the code on this question uses two connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misinterpreted the question you linked to.

You can certainly do a transaction that references tables in multiple databases, as long as the databases are hosted in the same instance of MySQL Server. You can even reference multiple databases in a single statement, by using [qualified table names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

The question you linked to is about databases hosted in *different* MySQL Server instances on different hosts. PDO has no support for coordinating commits against multiple MySQL servers.

---

Re your comment:

Yes, a transaction is scoped to a single connection, and a connection is made to a single MySQL Server instance. You can't make a transaction that spans multiple MySQL connections.

But within one connection to one MySQL Server instance, you can reference multiple databases.

The concept of a distributed transaction that spans multiple servers is supported by MySQL. It's called an [XA Transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xa.html). PDO does not have any direct support for XA Transactions.

Most applications do not need XA transactions, because they work on just one MySQL instance at a time.

Comment: please see edit. The wording of the other question I found says "Transactions are isolated within a single database." Is it more correct to say Transactions are isolated within a single database connection and server?

Comment: is this common to amny other DBMs, or just for mysql?

Comment: I haven't verified every other DBMS, but in my experience this is common.