# Spring framework - Split webapplication into modules and share authentication

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, war, spring-java-config

I am looking for split an application into modules using spring framework and java config.

For example:

- **Module1** - Admin console
- **Module2** - User console
- **Module3** - Public Site

It's possible share the same context and obtain that the 3 modules have same Session, ThreadPool etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at Spring Session project: http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/ . You can use Redis as a session storage and all modules can access those shared objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you also know how to share the ThreadPool and PesistenceSession?

Comment: I didn't really get what you ment by sharing a TheadPool. As for the PersistenceSession, I suppose you care about having a shared transaction among nodes, but that is not really a good idea. The reasons are discussed well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128377/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-distributed-transactions-across-multiple-databases