# Distributed transaction using spring and spring jdbctemplate

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I have two datasource with two schema in oracle, I am performing unittest but it is failing. I want if the second transaction failed then it should rollback the first trasaction. Below is my code.

```
package com.test.db;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.AfterTransaction;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.BeforeTransaction;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

//@EnableTransactionManagement
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="/META-INF/spring/data-source-context.xml")
public class MultipleDatasourceTests {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private JdbcTemplate otherJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSources(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            @Qualifier("otherDataSource") DataSource otherDataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.otherJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(otherDataSource);
    }

    @BeforeTransaction
    public void clearData() {
        jdbcTemplate.update("delete from T_ORACLE1");
        otherJdbcTemplate.update("delete from T_ORACLE1");
    }

    @AfterTransaction
    public void checkPostConditions() {

        int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt("select count(*) from T_ORACLE1");
        // This change was rolled back by the test framework
        assertEquals(0, count);

        count = otherJdbcTemplate.queryForInt("select count(*) from T_ORACLE1");
        // This rolls back as well if the connections are managed together
        assertEquals(0, count);

    }


    /**
     * Vanilla test case for two inserts into two data sources. Both should roll
     * back.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void testInsertIntoTwoDataSources() throws Exception {
        jdbcTemplate.update("delete from T_ORACLE1");
        otherJdbcTemplate.update("delete from T_ORACLE2");

        int count = jdbcTemplate.update(
                "INSERT into T_ORACLE1 (id,name,foo_date) values (?,?,null)", 0,
                "foo");
        assertEquals(1, count);

        count = otherJdbcTemplate
                .update(
                        "INSERT into T_ORACLE2 (id,operation,name,audit_date) values (?,?,?,?)",
                        1, "INSERT", "foo", new Date());
        assertEquals(1, count);

    }

    /**
     * Shows how to check the operation on the inner data source to see if it
     * has already been committed, and if it has do something different, instead
     * of just hitting a {@link DataIntegrityViolationException}.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void testInsertWithCheckForDuplicates() throws Exception {


        int count = jdbcTemplate.update(
                "INSERT into T_ORACLE1 (id,name,foo_date) values (?,?,null)", 0,
                "foo");
        assertEquals(1, count);

        count = otherJdbcTemplate.update(
                        "UPDATE T_ORACLE2 set operation=?, name=?, audit_date=? where id=?",
                        "UPDATE", "foo", new Date(), 0);

        if (count == 0) {
            count = otherJdbcTemplate.update(
                            "INSERT into T_ORACLE2 (id,operation,name,audit_date) values (?,?,?,?)",
                            0, "INSERT", "foo", new Date());
        }

        assertEquals(1, count);

    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.*"/>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/TESTDB1" />
        <property name="username" value="ORACLE1"/>
        <property name="password" value="ORACLE1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="otherDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/TESTDB2" />
        <property name="username" value="ORACLE2"/>
        <property name="password" value="ORACLE2"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="com.test.db.MultiTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManagers">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                </bean>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="otherDataSource" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>


package com.test.db;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionStatus;


public class MultiTransactionManager extends
        AbstractPlatformTransactionManager {

    private List<PlatformTransactionManager> transactionManagers = new ArrayList<PlatformTransactionManager>();
    private ArrayList<PlatformTransactionManager> reversed;

    public void setTransactionManagers(
            List<PlatformTransactionManager> transactionManagers) {
        this.transactionManagers = transactionManagers;
        reversed = new ArrayList<PlatformTransactionManager>(
                transactionManagers);
        Collections.reverse(reversed);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doBegin(Object transaction, TransactionDefinition definition)
            throws TransactionException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<DefaultTransactionStatus> list = (List<DefaultTransactionStatus>) transaction;
        for (PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager : transactionManagers) {
            DefaultTransactionStatus element = (DefaultTransactionStatus) transactionManager
                    .getTransaction(definition);
            list.add(0, element);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doCommit(DefaultTransactionStatus status)
            throws TransactionException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<DefaultTransactionStatus> list = (List<DefaultTransactionStatus>) status
                .getTransaction();
        int i = 0;
        for (PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager : reversed) {
            TransactionStatus local = list.get(i++);
            try {
                transactionManager.commit(local);
            } catch (TransactionException e) {
                logger.error("Error in commit", e);
                // Rollback will ensue as long as rollbackOnCommitFailure=true
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doGetTransaction() throws TransactionException {
        return new ArrayList<DefaultTransactionStatus>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doRollback(DefaultTransactionStatus status)
            throws TransactionException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<DefaultTransactionStatus> list = (List<DefaultTransactionStatus>) status
                .getTransaction();
        int i = 0;
        TransactionException lastException = null;
        for (PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager : reversed) {
            TransactionStatus local = list.get(i++);
            try {
                transactionManager.rollback(local);
            } catch (TransactionException e) {
                // Log exception and try to complete rollback 
                lastException = e;
                logger.error("Error in rollback", e);
            }
        }
        if (lastException!=null) {
            throw lastException;
        }
    }

}
```

My pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springsource.open</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-best-db-db</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Spring Best Efforts DB-DB</name>
    <description><![CDATA[Sample project showing multi DataSource transaction 
processing with Spring using best efforts 1PC.
]]> </description>
    <properties>
        <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
        <spring.framework.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>strict</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.test.failure.ignore>false</maven.test.failure.ignore>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>fast</id>
            <properties>
                <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>avalon-framework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>avalon-framework</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>logkit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logkit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.1.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.marcus-nl.btm/btm-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.marcus-nl.btm</groupId>
            <artifactId>btm-spring</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-mk1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

TABLE IN ORACLE1 database
create table T_ORACLE1 (
    id integer not null primary key,
    name varchar(80),
    foo_date timestamp
);
```

Table in ORACLE2 database

```
create table T_ORACLE2 (
    id integer not null primary key,
    operation varchar(20),
    name varchar(80),
    audit_date timestamp
);
```

I googled to use BitronixTransactionManager but, did  not get any clue how to configure for two datasource.

It seems we can use hibernate but, I don't want to use hibernate. I want either jdbctemplate with sql query or simple jdbc.

The error I am getting is

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot activate transaction synchronization - already active
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.initSynchronization(TransactionSynchronizationManager.java:270)

I am new to distributed transaction. Could you please help me on this? Is it possible to use two datasource but one transactionmanager?

Comment: Can you not avoid the distributed transaction? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/887426/479159

Answer (score 1):

You have to use XA datasources if you want to achieve distributed transactions and the transaction manager has to support XA transactions as well.

Using the Bitronix transaction manager should do it, but you have to use XA datasource as well: an Oracle-based implementation seems to be available in Oracle's JDBC driver (cf. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13731/thirdpartytx.htm#WLJTA266).

You can find an example of Spring configuration for Bitronix here: https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/652599/Example-distributed-XA-transaction-confi/, just make sure to adjust the datasources properties to use `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource` instead of the PostgreSQL one.

Note however that XA/distributed transactions are no silver bullet and won't be able to cope some classes of problem (e.g. network failures); you should really think to possible alternatives before taking that road.

Comment: I know we can use XAdatasouce but I don’t want to use any jpa, I want use only JDBC or springtemplate

Comment: You may just ignore use the Hibernate related part in the referenced Spring configuration file (just pick datasource and transaction manager configuration elements).